# Oracle with Terminal Services

Tags: windows-server-2008, oracle-11g

We have a Windows Server 2008 that is running Oracle 11g.  The server was configured for terminal services for administration.  This only allowed 2 people to remote to the server at a time.

Today I upgraded the terminal services so that more people can log on at once.  After the upgrade, Oracle isn't working.  Specifically, the website that uses the database reports ora 12514 error.  Sql Developer can't connect to the database on the local machine.

All of this was working just minutes before I did the upgrade and I have searched to try to determine what to change after modifying terminal services and found very little information.

Any thoughts?

Comment: TNS related issue, belongs on Serverfault

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that administration mode (2 users + console) and terminal services mode are two *very* different things.

You really have to consider rebuilding the machine if you want to use it like that, and Oracle probably don't support that mode anyway.

Why do you need more then two people anyway?

The vast majority of day-to-day administration should be doable by using the same admin tool just connecting to a remote server.

Here's a starter on the different modes:

http://blogs.technet.com/perfguru/archive/2008/02/06/terminal-services-remote-administration-and-application-mode.aspx